# margin value in negative not working for IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I have a header logo where I'm adding one more image on the left of this logo.
I have used `margin-left` property and works perfectly across all major browsers except IE6.
As a bit of a research I used `position:relative`property to fix this negative value.
But no luck. Here's the code I used.

in the `<body>` section I'm using this

```
<div id="logo">
<span style="position:relative;margin-left:-400px"><img src="image path"/>
</span>
</div>
```

now the DIV id="logo"
has following css styles

```
#logo {
    background: url("../images/logo.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 solid black;
    float: right;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 387px;
}
```

Comment: Many features are just unavailable for IE6 such as transparent PNGs. I  guess what you described is among them.

Comment: I'm not using a transparent PNG in fact its Jpeg ..

Comment: Sorry but I'm just providing an example. What I mean is that some problems of IE6 can hardly have a solution :(

Comment: If you can tell the layout you wanted, maybe there's some implementation other than the margin-left way.

Comment: @rhgb I have edited my question ...pls check.

Comment: I realized that maybe I missed something. Try change **span** to **div** first.

Comment: what a horrible markup. what do u want to do? you want to show span on the leftside of logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works well on my IETester - IE6 mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type='text/css'>
#logo {
    background: url("logo.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #EEE;
    border: 0 solid black;
    float: right;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 387px;
}
#logo span {
    position:relative;
    left:-400px;
    background:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo">
<span><img src="logo.png" alt="" />
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. maybe you should use something like this:

```
<div id="logo-wrapper">
    <div id="logo" style="float:right;"></div>
    <div style="float:right;"><img src="logo.png" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If an element has floating, in this case IE6 doubles the margin value. So if you want to move 400px to left, you should separately for IE6 write `margin-left: -200px`

```
#logo{position:relative}
span {position:absolute:left:-400px}
```

Comment: Try without margin. with absolute positioning

Answer (score 1):

Yes IE6 does not support negative margin-padding values so you can play with positioning with the use left right position negative or positive for getting your desired results......

like this:-

HTML

```
<div id="logo">
<span>span</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #logo {
    background: red;
    border: 0 solid black;
    float: right;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 387px;
}

#logo span {
position:relative;
left:-200px;
background:yellow;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `position:relative` with the `left` or the `right` attributes to position it in the right place. Or write specific styles for IE browser.

```
 .header{
     position:relative;
     left: -200px;
   }
```

Comment: try with margin-left instead of left.